# Ask for SSH key password every time

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to set up 2 factor authentication to SSH in some of our servers and I would like to prompt for password EVERYTIME you are trying to access it.

I could set up a password on my key doing ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/mykey but on OSX it asks me the the password I created only once.

Is there a way to prompt for password everytime?

Comment: i'm no expert but it loks like https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/ "If you're on OS X Leopard or later your keys can be saved in the system's keychain to make your life even easier. Most Linux installations will automatically start ssh-agent for you when you log in." <-- what if you kill ssh-agent?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't really answer my question ... I am looking for a way to enforce password everytime

Comment: I haven't really used password phrasing on my keys, so i'm no expert, and i'm guessing wildly, but you said that on osx it only asks the first time. So I thought maybe your experience is that on other OSs it asks every time, and then the reason why it stores it in a keychain so you only enter it once, so i'm suggesting you kill the process that causes that and it'd ask you every time. though i'm guessing, but if you understand the logic of what i'm saying then you'd see that I am aware that you are "looking for a way to enforce password everytime"